# TableView inside a UITableViewCell not getting detected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two UITableViews : tableviews1 and tableview2.

tableview2 is inside the UITableViewCell of tableview1. When i am clickng on the uitableviewcell of tableview2, its not responding but tableview1 tableviewcell is getting detected.

Can anyone help with this issue?

This is code i am using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (tableView == orderFoodDetailTableview) {

    if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
}
    else {


cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  [self addUItableViewAsSubView :cell];

        }

  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }

    return cell;
}



- (void)addUITableViewAsSubView:(UITableViewCell *)cell{

    portionSelected_yVal = [sArray count]*25;
    portionTableview = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, height+53, 140, portionSelected_yVal)];
    portionTableview.delegate = self;
    portionTableview.dataSource = self;
    portionTableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    portionTableview.hidden = YES;
    portionTableview.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    portionTableview.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    portionTableview.layer.cornerRadius=2.0f;
    [cell addSubview:portionTableview];
}
```

Comment: have you set the delegate of the tableview2?

Comment: Yes, I am doing that.

Comment: Why not post some related code?

Comment: You cn check the code i have added it.

Comment: I confess, I've never actually heard of someone trying to nest a `UITableView` **inside** of a `UITableViewCell`. Although you can nest `UIScrollView` fairly easily, I suspect that table views have some additional touch logic that's interfering with your nesting. What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish functionality wise? Perhaps there is an alternative approach?

Comment: On a tableViewCell i have a button on the clicked of which i have to show a drop down box made of UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

For the Purpose you have mentioned (in your comments), You can dynamically adjust the height of the `UITableViewCell` of `TableView1`, while user touches down the tableviewcell. Touching again that cell you can adjust it back at the normal size.

I hope you are getting my point.

---

**EDIT**

You have to check for which tableView you want to do the actions in `UITableView`'s common Delegate methods.

Say for e.g. you have two tableviews T1 and T2.

then in following method you have to check first, that for which tableview (T1 or T2), the method is being called.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == T1)
        // Return number of sections for T1;
    else if (tableView == T2) 
        // Return number of sections for T2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == T1)
        // Return number of rows for T1;
    else if (tableView == T2) 
        // Return number of rows for T2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == T1)
        // Create and Return cell for T1;
    else if (tableView == T2) 
        // Create and Return cell for T2;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == T1)
        // Do stuff for T1 related actions;
    else if (tableView == T2) 
        // Do stuff for T2 related actions;
}
```

Is it clear ?

Comment: Yes. That i have already done but the problem is i am not able to detect delegate methods for tableView2. When i am clicked on the UITableViewCell of tableView2.Delegate methods of tableView1 is getting called instead of tableView2.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're never going to get the proper callbacks. UITableViews have a lot of underlying code handling the touch events. What you can do is respond to the method `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and if it's tableView1 (the top table view) and an index path that contains a table view within the cell, return `nil`.

Comment: That's really just a guess and you'll have to play with it. Hope it works.